# core dump when gem install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to install rails on my server running Gentoo 2.2 but somehow always get a "core dumped" message when trying `sudo gem install rails`.
I compiled both Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 and also tried using rbenv but they all end up with the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0035 p:---- s:0165 e:000164 CFUNC  :parse
c:0034 p:0050 s:0160 e:000159 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205
c:0033 p:0014 s:0153 E:ffffff34 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153
c:0032 p:0014 s:0148 e:000147 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129
c:0031 p:0036 s:0142 e:000141 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:897
c:0030 p:0019 s:0137 e:000136 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/package.rb:398 [FINISH]

...follows about 20 lines of similar message
```

I tried `sudo gem install psych`, deleting `/usr/local/lib/ruby/*`, compiling the latest RubyGems, reinstalling libyaml, and pretty much all I can think of but no luck.
I'm quite new to Ruby and I'm not really sure what `psych.rb` nor `parser.parse yaml, filename` does, which is where the "Bus Error" seems to be occurring.

```
def self.parse_stream yaml, filename = nil, &block
  if block_given?
    parser = Psych::Parser.new(Handlers::DocumentStream.new(&block))
    parser.parse yaml, filename
  else
    parser = self.parser
    parser.parse yaml, filename
    parser.handler.root
  end 
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I went to bed after running `./configure --with-opt-dir=/usr/local && make && make install` as `su` and woke up to find `gem` running perfectly fine!
I'm guessing it's the `--with-opt-dir=/usr/local` option that made it work (although I've tried setting that option before, I believe it wasn't `/usr/local`).

Comment: Have you installed `libyaml` on your platform? If not then perhaps installing that and recompiling Ruby might help (it looks like it's crashing inside a the C YAML parsing library).

Comment: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/119#issuecomment-3608033

Comment: Casper-- Thanks for the comment! I tried reinstalling `libyaml` again but still couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: @Casper or NigoroJr - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn Thx..thats OK. Your answer is the best. Let's let that stand.

Comment: Thank you guys, I should've made it an answer instead of editing. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter...

[Casper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823617/casper) linked to the likely root cause issue filed on GitHub here: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/119#issuecomment-3608033

Then several hours later, [NigoroJr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2580849/nigorojr) confirmed that recompiling from source solved the issue, aligning with comments in the aforementioned GitHub ticket:

> I went to bed after running `./configure --with-opt-dir=/usr/local &&
>   make && make install` as `su` and woke up to find `gem` running
>   perfectly fine! I'm guessing it's the `--with-opt-dir=/usr/local`
>   option that made it work (although I've tried setting that option
>   before, I believe it wasn't `/usr/local`).